# What is this puzzle with identical wooden pieces?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles, burr-puzzle

I received a bag of wooden pieces, but cannot figure out what the puzzle is supposed to be.  I've tried several burr options and several Alketruse puzzles, but cannot find the correct configuration.  All pieces are the same.  There are 23 total (not sure how many it should be because it could be several puzzles). What puzzle is this?

[image: 23 identical pieces like this one]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you specify where you got the bag of pieces from? Do you know what the goal of the puzzle would be (what shape you're supposed to form)? Or any other details that may be relevant. Every bit of information will help us identify the puzzle.

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea what the puzzle is supposed to be.  I wish I did. :). I received the puzzle along with a stack of games at the school I work with for After School Programming.  I hate to throw it away just because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminds me of those wooden-cage types of puzzles.

The most common wooden cage is probably the one on the lower left, [in this box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005JEE3IW). See also [the drawing here](https://www.jbd-jouetsenbois.com/images/Image/CT040-N_1353448818.jpg). You have a [video of the solution here](https://youtu.be/t39NkvjEF08). This is a 12 piece puzzle, so maybe you have two of this.

[EDIT] Yours looks more like this ["Double Lock-a-Ball Wooden Puzzle"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XW29S11) (24 pieces + one wooden ball). Here is the [solution in video](https://youtu.be/VpTJqLAQWF8).
￼

Comment: Oh my goodness!  Yes, double lock-a-ball looks like it.  I will have to make another piece for it!  I will try it this evening. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much! Now I just need to make 1 more piece to make it complete.  My daughter rolled a string ball for the center, so it worked great. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could be helpful.